# This code shows user list bt how to conver this into MVC model in Nodejs and mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

This code shows user list but how to convert this into MVC model in Nodejs and mysql?
The code is given below.....

// SHOW LIST OF USERS

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    req.getConnection(function(error, conn) 
    {
        conn.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC',function(err,  
         rows, fields) {
        //if(err) throw err
        if (err) {
            req.flash('error', err)
            res.render('user/list', {
                title: 'User List', 
                data: ''
            })
        } else {
            // render to views/user/list.ejs template file
            res.render('user/list', {
                title: 'User List', 
                data: rows
            })
        }
      })
  })
})
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Do you want to have a MVC structure in your Node JS project?

Comment: yes i want mvc structure . how to model, view and controller of above code?